# How to identify what is printing on screen in linux?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdout, stderr

I'm using a library in my C++ application and trying to capture all the output in a file. I tried to redirect the stderr to stdout and then stdout to a file like so:

```
./a.out 2>&1 > out.txt
```

This captures pretty much everything in my application but there are still some output on the console related to the library I'm using. My question is:

- Are there anything besides stdout/stderr? (other than stdin)
- If there are, how can I identify these in my case?
- And then how can I redirect these to the same file?

**Note:** In case someone is familiar, library is called [SystemC](http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/systemc) (which is an event driven simulation library/language on top of C++ for mainly system/hardware design).

Answer (score 2):

You must set output file before any stream-to-stream redirection, else bash can't detect file name to output. In your case you can see stderr output.

See [bash redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) reference manual.

Solution:

```
./a.out >out.txt 2>&1
```

Or just:

```
./a.out &>out.txt
```

Comment: hmmm, that worked to some extend (+1) but there are still some output on my screen.

Comment: What output is left on your screen?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, well I think what might be happening is that your program is printing to the controlling terminal. One possibility could be to have your program run as a daemon with no controlling terminal. I have a `C` function that I call to turn my code into a daemon, I got this from a book called [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/) which I highly recommend.

```
#define BD_NO_CHDIR 01 /* Don't chdir("/") */
#define BD_NO_CLOSE_FILES 02 /* Don't close all open files */
#define BD_NO_REOPEN_STD_FDS 04 /* Don't reopen stdin, stdout, and
               stderr to /dev/null */
#define BD_NO_UMASK0 010 /* Don't do a umask(0) */
#define BD_MAX_CLOSE 8192 /* Maximum file descriptors to close if
             sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) is indeterminate */


int becomeDaemon(int flags){

  int maxfd, fd, new_stdout;
  switch (fork()) { /* Become background process */
  case -1: return -1;
  case 0: break; /* Child falls through... */
  default: _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); /* while parent terminates */
  }
  if (setsid() == -1) /* Become leader of new session */
   return -1;
  switch (fork()) { /* Ensure we are not session leader */
  case -1: return -1;
  case 0: break;
  default: _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  if (!(flags & BD_NO_UMASK0))
    umask(0); /* Clear file mode creation mask */
 if (!(flags & BD_NO_CHDIR))
   chdir("/"); /* Change to root directory */
 if (!(flags & BD_NO_CLOSE_FILES)) { /* Close all open files */
   maxfd = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
   if (maxfd == -1) /* Limit is indeterminate... */
     maxfd = BD_MAX_CLOSE; /* so take a guess */
   for (fd = 0; fd < maxfd; fd++)
     close(fd);
 }


 if (!(flags & BD_NO_REOPEN_STD_FDS)) {

   /*
     STDIN = 0
     STDOUT = 1
     STDERR = 2
   */

   close(0); /* Reopen standard fd's to /dev/null */
   fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
   if (fd != 0) /* 'fd' should be 0 */
     return -1;
   if (dup2(0, 1) != 1)
     return -1;
   if (dup2(0, 2) != 2)
     return -1;
  }



 return 0;
}
```

Now I suppose that you can change the line `open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)` to `open("/home/you/output.txt", O_RDWR)` and redirect the output there. Ofcourse then you wouldn't be able to directly input from the terminal to your program, but from the sounds of the error message you're getting I think you're using a socket anyway so could possible write a client to do that for you if it was necessary.

Hope that helps.

Comment: For some of the applications I have, I'm not allowed to change the source code. Even if I could, this looks more complicated than I could handle so I would rather not dare to give it a try. I guess I was hoping for a simpler solution, but thanks anyway.. +1